# Login redirect to main domain using django-subdomains

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-subdomains

My project is using `django-subdomains` and `django-allauth` to handle subdomains and auth system.

It has a couple of subdomains: company1.project.com, company2.project.com

Some of views are using `@login_required` decorator that redirects user to `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'` at settings.py
Ex: user is at `company1.project.com` and calls view which redirects him to `company1.project.com/login/`

I need to redirect users to the `project.com/login/`

`django-subdomains` have tool `reverse('login')` which returns `project.com/login/` if I do not pass subdomain argument, but I cannot use it in settings for `LOGIN_URL` because django apps are not loaded yet.